# Unable to start mysql , if provided data directory exist on ntfs file stystem

Tags: permissions, mysql

```
sudo mysqld --debug
2016-06-06 11:02:35 0 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-06-06 11:02:35 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-06-06 11:02:35 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.30-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 25351 ...
2016-06-06 11:02:35 25351 [Warning] Can't create test file /mnt/01D0900CA5E8F760/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQLServer5.6/ashish-ratan.lower-test
2016-06-06 11:02:35 25351 [Warning] Can't create test file /mnt/01D0900CA5E8F760/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQLServer5.6/ashish-ratan.lower-test
```

mysqld config:

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
#datadir        = /var/lib/mysql
datadir     =/mnt/01D0900CA5E8F760/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQLServer5.6
tmpdir      = /tmp
```

What exactly I've in the case

Using Windows mysql data directory in linux, as i have uploaded my large DB on NTFS , now I want to use that directory in linux .

Comment: Why don't you move data to ext4 partition? Sounds as if incorrect permissions are causing the problem. It would helpful if you could add command used to mount NTFS partition.

Comment: What exactly I'm trying to do? -> You tell us? How do we know?

Comment: @GoranMiskovic But that's not the solution for the situation, for example my case, i don't have 60 GB on my ext4 partition so moving is not possible.

Comment: @AshishRatan I did not say that it is solution. I just asked why. :) Anyway, could you provide mount command and confirm that user _mysql_ can write to data directory.

Comment: @GoranMiskovic nthat is what I'm searching for actually, my mysql is working and running on my linux box when provide the data directory on ext4 (/ partition ), but i want to re use my Windows data directory in linux.

Comment: @AshishRatan Nevertheless, it's hard to help without knowing mount command used to mount NTFS partition and knowing if the user _mysql_ can read/write to the data directory.

Comment: @GoranMiskovic this is other partition that i made by partitioning and auto mount at startup,

Comment: @AshishRatan could post output of commands `mount -l` and `ls -lh /mnt/01D0900CA5E8F760/ProgramData/MySQL/` please?

Answer (score 1):

After changing the data directory you need to change the Apparmor settings to solve the permission issue

1. Open `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`
2. Comment out `/var/lib/mysql/ r,
               /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,`
3. Then `/mnt/01D0900CA5E8F760/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQLServer5.6/ r,
         /mnt/01D0900CA5E8F760/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQLServer5.6/** rwk,`
4. Also see to it that the permissions are properly given to the data directories.
5. Try to restart the MySQL service again.

Comment: I guess it should work. I'll apply and Accept the answer if resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ashish, 
Make sure that your NTFS partition is mounted with read-write option. You can mount your NTFS partition `/dev/sda1` using following command.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/ntfs/
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/ntfs/
```

Comment: My partition is eligible for read/write. i do copy paste my general data inside ntfs . It's the issue with my mysql instance.